# Why Non-Unicode apps system locale makes Unicode fonts with symbol charset displayed incorrectly?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, fonts, non-unicode

I'm trying to display Unicode chars from Wingdings font (it's Unicode TrueType font supporting symbol charset only).
It's displayed correctly on my Win7/64 system using corresponding regional OS settings:

- Formats: Russian
- Location: Russia
- System locale (AKA Language for Non-Unicode applications): English

But if I switch System locale to Russian, Unicode characters with codes > 127 are displayed incorrectly (replaced with boxes).

My application is created as using Unicode Charset in Visual Studio, it calls only Unicode Windows API functions.

Also I noted that several Windows apps also display such chars incorrectly with symbol fonts (Symbol, Wingdings, Webdings etc), e.g. Notepad, Beyond Compare 3. But WordPad and MS Office apps aren't affected.

Here is minimal code snippet (resources cleanup skipped for brevity):

```
LOGFONTW lf = { 0 };
lf.lfCharSet = SYMBOL_CHARSET;
lf.lfHeight = 50;
wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, L"Wingdings");

HFONT f = CreateFontIndirectW(&lf);

SelectObject(hdc, f);

// First two chars displayed OK, 3rd and 4th aren't (replaced with boxes) if
// Non-Unicode apps language is NOT English.
TextOutW(hdc, 10, 10, L"\x7d\x7e\x81\xfc");
```

So the question is: why the hell Non-Unicode apps language setting affects Unicode apps?

And what is the correct (and most simple) way to display `SYMBOL_CHARSET` fonts without dependency to OS system locale?

Comment: Sounds like a broken machine problem.  Technically it is possible, the default system locale affects font substitution rules.  Which are used if the font isn't actually available or is missing glyphs.  Boxes appear when the substitution couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't look so. The result is stable if I switch Non-Unicode apps setting to English and back to Russian several times. Reproduced on another Win7 machine as well. Also symbol chars with codes 0..127 are OK. It looks like WinAPI bug - Unicode string is not processed as is, but translated according to system locale despite the SYMBOL_CHARSET is used on logfont creation. Like using ANSI API instead of Unicode...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that Wingdings font is actually **non-Unicode** font. It supports Unicode partially, so some symbols are still displayed correctly. See **@Adrian McCarthy**'s answer for details about how it's probably works under the hood.

Also see more info here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/wingdings
and here: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

So what can we do to avoid such problems? I found several ways:

**1. Quick & dirty**

Fall back to ANSI version of API, as **@user1793036** suggested:

```
TextOutA(hdc, 10, 10, "\x7d\x7e\x81\xfc"); // Displayed correctly!
```

**2. Quick & clean**

Use special Unicode range `F0` ([Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Private_Use_Areas)) instead of ASCII character codes. It's supported by Wingdings:

```
TextOutW(hdc, 10, 10, L"\xf07d\xf07e\xf081\xf0fc"); // Displayed correctly!
```

To explore which Unicode symbols are actually supported by font some font viewer can be used, e.g. [dp4 Font Viewer](http://us.fontviewer.de/)

**3. Slow & clean, but generic**

But what to do if you don't know which characters you have to display and which font actually will be used? Here is most universal solution - draw text by glyphs to avoid any undesired translations:

```
void TextOutByGlyphs(HDC hdc, int x, int y, const CStringW& text)
{
   CStringW glyphs;

   GCP_RESULTSW gcpRes = {0};
   gcpRes.lStructSize = sizeof(GCP_RESULTS);
   gcpRes.lpGlyphs = glyphs.GetBuffer(text.GetLength());
   gcpRes.nGlyphs = text.GetLength();

   const DWORD flags = GetFontLanguageInfo(hdc) & FLI_MASK;
   GetCharacterPlacementW(hdc, text.GetString(), text.GetLength(), 0,
     &gcpRes, flags);
   glyphs.ReleaseBuffer(gcpRes.nGlyphs);

   ExtTextOutW(hdc, x, y, ETO_GLYPH_INDEX, NULL, glyphs.GetString(),
      glyphs.GetLength(), NULL);
}

TextOutByGlyphs(hdc, 10, 10, L"\x7d\x7e\x81\xfc"); // Displayed correctly!
```

Note `GetCharacterPlacementW()` function usage. For some unknown reason similar function `GetGlyphIndicesW()` would not work returning 'unsupported' dummy values for chars > 127.

Comment: Nicely done.  This is going to help a lot of people in the future.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Hope so. Thanks for the idea to deal with glyphs!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I think is happening:

1. The Wingdings font doesn't have Unicode mappings (a cmap table?).  (You can see this by using charmap.exe:  the `Character set` drop down control is grayed out.)
2. For fonts without Unicode mappings, I think Windows assumes that it depends on the "Language for Non-Unicode applications" setting.
3. When that's English, Windows (probably) uses code page 1252, and all the values map to themselves.
4. When that's Russian, Windows (probably) uses code page 1251, and then tries to remap them.
5. The `'\x81'` value in code page 1251 maps to `U+0403`, which obviously doesn't exist in the font, so you get a box.  Similarly the, `'\xFC'` maps to `U+044C`.

I assumed that if you used `ExtTextOutW` with the `ETO_GLYPH_INDEX` flag, Windows wouldn't try to interpret the values at all and just treat them as glyph indexes into the font.  But that assumption is wrong.

However, there is another flag called `ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE`, which is reserved, but, empirically, it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree with this. I recall that on a Unicode build of my app some symbols would get the rectangle glyph, where in the Ansi build they would display fine. When I searched online I discovered that WingDings is only partially supported in Unicode. My solution was to draw each character using DrawTextA. This worked for me because I was only drawing individual characters.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clue, suddenly I realized that Wingdings is actually non-Unicode font! :-) Don't like to fall back to ANSI API, will dig it a bit deeper to elaborate a proper solution.

Comment: Unfortunately ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE is not working, still same boxes are drawn